# GET request with $function in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

**Summary:**
I am trying to Combine the result of Mongodb aggregation with a third party API and I can't find anything relevant to it.

**Explanation:**
The below `Express` route finds all Games that comes after the provided Date and have not been cancelled. The next step is to get some data of that single game from the Third party API and attach it to the object and continue further in the pipeline

**Issue:**
It seems that you can't have a `XHR` request inside the `$function` (I didn't find anything in the official documentation so I'm not sure on that)

```js
        const today = moment();
        today.year(2021);
        today.month(5);
        let response = await Game.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $and: [
                            { $gte: ["$date", moment(today).startOf('day').toDate()] },
                            { $eq: ["$canceled", false] },
                        ]
                    }
    
                }
            },
            { $sort: { date: 1 } },
            {
                $addFields: {
                    boxScore: {
                        $function:
                        {
                            body: async function (season, week, home_team) {
                                const result = await axios.get(
                                    `SINGLEGAMEURL/${season}/${week}/${home_team}`,
                                    {
                                        headers: {
                                            'Subscription-Key': 'SOMEKEY',
                                        },
                                    }
                                );
                                return result.data;
                            },
                            args: ["$season", '$week', 'home_team'],
                            lang: "js"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]);
```

I would really appreciate any help/direction on this, Cheers!

Comment: Are you getting any errors? The JavaScript function runs on the database server. So, the JS engine which is part of the server need to have that external function you are calling within the `$function`. The call you are making within the `$function` is using some software components which are not part of the normal JS, I see.

Comment: No I'm not getting any errors, the field `boxScore` returns an empty object. I do get an error saying `Mongodb Error: axios is not defined` if i remove `async`

Comment: When the server calls "body" it will do so synchronously, which will return a promise before even attempting to execute the awaited function call.

Comment: I think got that much by now so the question is: Is thereAnyway around this ?

Comment: why you dont do that call after you get the aggregate results? you can do this in javascript on the results.As far as i know only `function(){}` i allowed as body, and i dont think there is a way to use libraries, you need i think just JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that you can use asynchronous functions in `$function`, because they return a promise that resolves to `result.data`, rather than the data themselves. Instead, consider performing the asynchronous operation in your express middleware, *after* the MongoDB operation. Something like this:

```js
app.use("/path", async function(req, res) {
  const today = moment();
  today.year(2021);
  today.month(5);
  let response = await Game.aggregate([
    {$match: ...},
    {$sort: {date: 1}}
  ]).toArray();
  await Promise.all(response.map(row => axios.get(
    `SINGLEGAMEURL/${row.season}/${row.week}/${row.home_team}`,
    {headers: {'Subscription-Key': 'SOMEKEY'}}
  ).then(function(result) {
    row.boxScore = result.data;
  })));
  res.json(response);
});
```

(Probably the `Promise.all` can be avoided, but I'm not experienced enough with async/await to know how.)